# Viewing 8 bit RAW image file in openCV

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, binary-data

I have a raw file which contains a header of 5 bytes containing the number of rows and columns in first two bits each . The 5th byte contains the number of bits for each pixel in the image which is 8 bits in all cases. The image data follows after that.

Since I am new to openCV, i want to ask how to view this RAW image file as an greyscale image using C++?

I know how to read binary data in C++ and have stored the image as a 2-D unsigned char array (since each pixel is 8 bit).

Can anyone please tell me how to view this data as image using openCV ?

I am using the below code , but getting a completely weird image :

```
void openRaw() {
    cv::Mat img(numRows, numCols,CV_8U,&(image[0][0]));
    //img.t();
    cv::imshow("img",img);  
    cv::waitKey();
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Rohit

Answer (score 1):

You have to convert it to an IplImage.

If you want to see it as a pure grey-scale image, its actually rather easy.

Example code I use in one application:

```
CvSize mSize;
mSize.height = 960;
mSize.width = 1280;

IplImage* image1 = cvCreateImage(mSize, 8, 1);
memcpy( image1->imageData, rawDataPointer, sizeOfImage);
cvNamedWindow( "corners1", 1 );
cvShowImage( "corners1", image1 );
```

At that point you have a valid IplImage, which you can then display. (last 2 lines of code display it)

If the image is bayer-tiled, you will have to convert to RGB.

Comment: how do i pass the rawDataPointer if the data is in a file?  and would sizeOfImage be height*width?

Comment: Well, you have to read the file first, and extract heigh / width from it, and then create a memory pointer to the read data. sizeOfImage is, for an 8bit greyscale image height*width, for RGB its height * width * 3.

Answer (score 0):

c++ notation:

```
cv::Mat img(rows,cols,CV_8U,ptrToDat);
cv::imwhow("img",img);
cv::waitkey();
```

*data should be saved columwise, otherewise use:

```
cv::Mat img(cols,rows,CV_8U,ptrToDat);
img=img.t();
cv::imwhow("img",img);
cv::waitkey();
```

Comment: How to give ptrToDat if the data is in a file? I am sorry i am not so good with C++ , can you provide some more code?